# PayPal (invalid scope) for accessing "services/shipping/trackers"

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

Dunno how to proceed. From glance I provided all access under `My apps & credentials`. But somehow not able to get these scopes that should provide me this `Access your PayPal transactional data`.

```sh
  https://uri.paypal.com/services/shipping/trackers/read 
  https://uri.paypal.com/services/shipping/trackers/readwrite
```

Getting this when adding `shipping/trackers`:
[image]

Full scope list:

```sh
   export PAYPAL_URL="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com"
   export PAYPAL_SCOPE="openid email profile https://uri.paypal.com/services/disputes/read-seller https://uri.paypal.com/services/disputes/update-seller 
   https://uri.paypal.com/services/reporting/search/read https://uri.paypal.com/services/shipping/trackers/read https://uri.paypal.com/services/shipping/trackers/readwrite"
```

My apps & Credential:
[image]

Comment: Not sure where you're getting the idea that you can request these scopes, but you need to be a PayPal partner to use transaction search as a third party, and presumably other scopes are also restricted

Comment: Thank you @PrestonPHX that can explain why I could not get pass that scope.  I took that scopes sample from this app  [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=939S7HqgJi4). So far it is only complaints to `services/shipping/trackers`. The rest scopes are passing.

Answer (score 0):

After opening a support ticket with PayPal issue got resolved! It was handled very professionally!

Comment: can you explain how did you solve it, please. It can help others like us with the same problem.

Comment: go to paypal support and open a case.  they will update scope.  no magic :)